# Error enabling offline persistence. Falling back to persistence disabled: FirebaseError: [code=unimplemented]:

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Can't enable Firestore persistence from React Native. It gives the following error.

> Error enabling offline persistence. Falling back to persistence disabled: FirebaseError: [code=unimplemented]: This platform is either missing IndexedDB or is known to have an incomplete implementation. Offline persistence has been disabled.

Comment: It sounds like your browser doesn't support the necessary APIs to implement persistence.

Comment: I am using React Native for mobile developments with my android real device. It should be supported.

Comment: If you think this is a bug, then post an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase